# Double integral of an exponential function .

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, multiple-integral

I need to integrate, 
$$I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y}\ dx\ dy$$

I tried using integration by parts for the first integrand but I am getting its value as zero.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean ,$I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y}\ dx\ dy$?

Comment: @TheIntegrator , thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Try to substitute some variable using $u = x+y$, and integrate with order $\int \int \cdots \mathrm dx\,\mathrm du$, with appropriate integral region.

Comment: The standard trick $\frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y}=\int_1^{\infty}e^{-(x+y)z}\,dz$ should work here, no?

Answer (score 3):

Set $x = uv$, $y=u(1-v)$, which changes the bounds to $0<u<\infty$ and $0<v<1$ (this is a common trick for integration over the first quadrant). Then $dx \, dy = u \, du \, dv $, and $x+y = u $, so the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u} \, du \, dv, $$
which is easy.